# run all cells jupyter notebook fail: one by one manually-yes, run al- no

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Thanks for all answers in advance

I am linux mint

I reopen my jupyter notebook do 'run all cells' it is supposed to make str to numeric among many other things.

When I go cell by cell and run the code manually cell by cell all is fine,
when i do 'run all cells' and occasionally check for the execution of pd.to_numeric , just for example, no effect.

Updated anaconda, and all components

Answer (score 1):

try `pip install ipykernel --upgrade`. It works for me.

Comment: I tried this, and I cannot connect to the kernel anymore.